# Errors and other weird stuff in haxe

Tags: javascript, html, haxe

I downloaded a project from TouchMyPixel and when I try to run it with FlashDevelop + haxe, I get the following error:

`"this target doesn't have an associated external IDE"`

It's quite hard to learn haxe when there are soooo few resources, and answers... 
Besides that does anyone have good learning resources regarding html5/js + box2d + haxe? Sample code or quick intro available for noobs like me?

Comment: It seems that the problem is with FlashDevelop. The project file might be too old or too new in comparison with your version. Just create a new FD project and replace the .hxproj file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like Waneck said, I just made a new project and it worked.

Comment: mark you answer as correct to let other user see, what solved the problem.